# How do I display my Products in Separate pages?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 Based shopping cart project and one of the requirements is to show 8 products per page. I have 21 products in total. This is how I'm showing them at the moment:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT ProductId, Products.CategoryId AS CategoryId, Name, ImageFileName, UnitCost"
            + ", SUBSTRING(Description, 1, 100) + '...' AS Description, isDownload, DownloadFileName "
            + "FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId ";

        String CategoryName = Request.QueryString.Get("CategoryName");
        if (CategoryName != null)
        {
            if (CategoryName.Length > 20 || CategoryName.IndexOf("'") > -1 || CategoryName.IndexOf("#") > -1)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SQL += "WHERE CategoryName = @p0";
            ViewBag.CategoryName = CategoryName;
        }
        var products = db.Products.SqlQuery(SQL, CategoryName);
        return View(products.ToList());
    }
```

This is the cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<PiClub.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shop";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
<h2>Shop</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Image
    </th>
    <th>
        Price
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th>
        Category
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="/Images/@item.ImageFileName" style="width:200px" />
    </td>

    <td style="text-align:right">
        @item.UnitCost
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Description
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Category.CategoryName
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="NavCart('@item.ProductId')" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Details" onclick="NavDetails('@item.ProductId')" />
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function NavDetails(ProductId) {
    window.location.replace("/Shop/Details?PrdouctId=" + ProductId);
}

function NavCart(ProductId) {
    window.location.replace("/OrderDetails/ShoppingCart?ProductId=" + ProductId);
}
</script>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: ideally you should use some kind of grid with paging like datatable to display products.

Comment: what i ended up doing is following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 3):

Put two parameters at your method, which will represent the page number and items per page:

```
public ActionResult Index(int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage)
```

Then add Skip and Take where you grab data from database:

```
var products = db.Products.SqlQuery(SQL, CategoryName)
                          .Skip(pageNumber * itemsPerPage)
                          .Take(itemsPerPage);
```

Then send parameters via url:

http://your-url/ControllerName/Index?pageNumber=2&itemsNumber=8

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `Skip` and `Take` to implement paging.

```
const int itemsPerPage = 8;
int currentPage = 0; // parameter to the passed; first page has index 0

var result = db.Products.SqlQuery(SQL, CategoryName)
                 .Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage)
                 .Take(itemsPerPage);
```